# C++ read global variable flag in namespace from std::async function

Tags: c++

So my use case is the following: I have a handful of functions and fields defined inside a namespace. One of these functions will initialize the fields, then run another function inside a call to std::async. The function called should run indefinitely until flagged to stop, most commonly from outside of its own thread. The basic code looks something like this

```
namespace Game
{
void Create() {
    Initialize();

    auto returned = std::async(RunGameLoop, std::ref(FLAGS));
}
}
```

Now, the way I have attempted to implement this is by initializing these flags in the namespace:

```
namespace Game
{
namespace // This is used because the fields and functions here should be for internal use only
{
bool stopped = false;
}
}
```

Inside the RunGameLoop function the basic structure is set up like this

```
namespace Game
{
namespace // This is used because the fields and functions here should be for internal use only
{
void RunGameLoop()
{
    while (!stopped)
    {
        // ... do stuff
    }
}
}
}
```

But seemingly due to how async works, if I change the value of `stopped` from anywhere other than inside the RunGameLoop function, the RunGameLoop function does not see any change. Presumably when creating the async function call, C++ simply copies all values in scope at the time of construction, passing them by value instead of reference.

My question is: How do I make this change noticeable inside the async function loop? Or even better: Is there a better way to communicate simple global flags like this with an async function in C++? I have experimented with using std::ref, passing pointers, and passing an entire map of flags by reference, but seemingly no changes made outside of the RunGameLoop function will be noticeable inside the RunGameLoop function.

<s>**Edit**: I've managed to replicate the issue in a minimal example, this program will run indefinitely, and indeed never reach the second std::cout statement, counterintuitively. The std::async call does, in fact, not seem to run the function asynchronously at all, which is a bit harsher than what I experienced in my own project. I acknowledge I might be misunderstanding how std::async is supposed to be used, but it seems like this code should work to me.</s>

**Edit 2:** I bungled my prior example, so I fixed it. Unfortunately now it seems to behave as expected, unlike my actual project:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

namespace test
{
namespace
{

std::atomic<bool> testbool = false;
std::future<void> returned;

void queryTestBool()
{
    while (!testbool)
    {

    }
    std::cout << "EXITED THREAD: " << std::boolalpha << testbool << std::endl;
}
}

void Initialize()
{
    testbool = false;
}

void Delete()
{
    testbool = !testbool;

    returned.get();
}

void Create()
{
    Initialize();

    returned = std::async(queryTestBool);
}
}

int main()
{
    using namespace test;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << testbool << std::endl;

    Create();

    Delete();

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << testbool << std::endl;
}
```

This program outputs

`false`

`EXITED THREAD: true`

`true`

meaning that not only does the Delete function successfully change the value of `testbool`, but that change is noticed in the asynchronous while loop. This last part is what isn't happening in my own project for some reason, even when I use std::atomic. I will investigate further.

Comment: You need some form of synchronization, for example making flag `atomic<bool>`, otherwise concurrent r/w access to this flag creates a data race which is an undefined behavior.

Comment: @VTT I have tried that, and while it is important for a number of other reasons, it doesn't actually fix this problem

Comment: I guess you should provide an mcve… If use of atomic here does not make changes visible than maybe the issue is something else, for example use of different `stopped` variables.

Comment: I'll see if I can recreate it in an MCVE. The issue is not, however, about general thread safety or having undefined behavior when a thread writes to a variable while another thread is reading it, but about providing a pointer to a global variable inside an std::async function instead of simply copying it, so I think whether or not I use std::atomic is irrelevant to my question.

Comment: I have provided an example that fails in a similar fashion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I feel massively stupid. After struggling with this for weeks, implementing all sorts of stuff, I finally discovered that the place my test called the Delete() function was being skipped because of a failed assertion that I didn't expect to make the test exit before running the rest... Mystery solved